# Ant not recognizing external command

Tags: ant, mule

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\SomeUser\Downloads\mule_test\build.xml:69: Problem: failed to create task or type cloudHubDeploy
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Command:

```
<target name="deploy" depends="package">
    <cloudHubDeploy username="usr" password="pswd" domain="${app.name}" applicationFile="${app.file}" />
</target>
```

using **ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar** but still ant not recognizing the command.

Answer (score 1):

`<cloudHubDeploy>` is a third-party task.  You'll need to include the source that defines it or reference its JAR.

A quick Google search yielded [this guide](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/deploying-your-mule-application-to-cloudhub-using-apache-ant/) and this [download link](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-packaging-tasks.git).

Comment: I have added the source, It compiled successfully but still giving me this error

Comment: @YashwanthSainath Have you added `<taskdef resource="org/mule/mulePackagingTasks.properties"/>` to your Ant script?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @whiskeyspider this is a 3rd party ANT task, which **always** means you're missing a jar from the ANT classpath.

The [README documentation](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-packaging-tasks#readme) explains what is required to enable the tasks:

> Ant is a tool for building Java applications, which can be extended by adding custom tasks. These tasks will let you build and deploy Mule applications.
>
> To use these tasks:
>
> ```
> Add -lib mule-anttasks.jar to your Ant command line, to put the classes that implement the tasks in Ant's classpath.
> Add <taskdef resource="org/mule/mulePackagingTasks.properties"/> to your Ant build file, to import the task definitions.
> ```

The mule-anttasks.jar could also be added to one of the following directories in order to ANT to pick it up at run-time:

- $ANT_HOME/lib
- $HOME/.ant/lib

Hope this helps.